# Is it true that stroked open path in Photoshop is impossible?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, technique

I need to use a Pen tool for drawing connected lines, like in Illustrator. But Photoshop always closes the path. Are there certain settings to avoid this?

Why 'What You See' is not What You Get' in Photoshop? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unclear what you are referring to... I can draw open paths with the **Pen Tool** and apply a stroke to them without issue in Photoshop CC.

[image]

If your paths "always close" then perhaps you have a *fill* set for the paths. Fills *must close* to be a fill. And you *really* don't want to get into the habit of applying fills to open paths. It's just not good practice.

Comment: They mean having more than one path inside one shape layer. You are obviously having two shape layers (as they have a different color). Try to draw what you have inside one layer, it is impossible (the first path closes itself).

Comment: Why would additional shape layers be an issue? If one wants total path control, Photoshop is a poor tool.. Illustrator is better.

Comment: When you have 100 identical parts of an object, it might be better to have them in one layer. Did you try it in Photoshop to see that it is impossible?

Comment: Your point is rather irrelevant. If you have that may paths, one is using the *wrong tool*, use Illustrator.

Comment: This question is about whether it is or is not possible in Adobe Photoshop. So your answer is irrelevant. Not everyone can afford two programs.

Comment: My answer is 100% accurate .. it **is** possible to stroke an open path. The question states *nothing* about multiple paths on the same shape layer. If you can't afford Illustrator, then use **Inkscape** which is a free vector editor. Photoshop is **not** and has never been the be-all-end-all for every project.

Comment: Simply because *you want to* pound in nails with a screwdriver, that doesn't mean it's the correct tool to use.